# J2ME Polish: Targeting Android, BlackBerry, and J2ME devices

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish

I’m working on an app which is required to run on multiple different platforms. The original code is written in J2ME (Java ME).

The documentation online regarding using J2ME Polish for targeting multiple platforms is scarce and difficult to follow.

Can anyone here offer advice on targeting these 3 platforms using one code base? I’m currently using NetBeans 7.3 + the J2ME Polish plugin.

I’d ideally like to support:

- Android 2.1+
- BlackBerry OS 5.0+
- J2ME/Java ME devices